# How to set up Basic Authentication sans SSL in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-services, basic-authentication

Folks,

I have an asmx web sevice being hotes in IIS 7 with only basic authentication enabled.

I am trying to test the basic authentication on my local machine before dealing with the SSL.

When testing using the following code...

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        MyCompanyExternalService.CClaim claim = new MyCompanyExternalService.CClaim();
        claim.Airline = "AA";
        claim.OrigCty = "MCO";
        claim.PaxFN = "John";
        claim.PaxLN = "Smith";
        claim.FileRef = "DL123321";
        claim.OrigDate = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/2001");
        claim.ClaimFor = MyCompanyExternalService.EReasonsForClaim.Pilferage;
        claim.AirlineClaimStatus = "Open";


        MyCompanyExternalService.wsMyCompanyImportSoapClient MyCompanyImportSoapClient 
            = new MyCompanyExternalService.wsMyCompanyImportSoapClient("wsMyCompanyImportSoap");
        MyCompanyImportSoapClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "My-PC\\chron";
        MyCompanyImportSoapClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "********";
        Assert.IsTrue(MyCompanyImportSoapClient.SubmitClaim(claim));
    }
```

.. I receive the following error:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with
>   client authentication scheme 'Basic'.
>   The authentication header received
>   from the server was 'Basic
>   realm="localhost"'.
>
> innerexception: The remote server
>   returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Here is my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="wsMyCompanyImportSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" realm="" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost/MyCompany/MyCompanyWebServiceApp/wsMyCompanyImport.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsMyCompanyImportSoap"
                contract="MyCompanyExternalService.wsMyCompanyImportSoap"
                name="wsMyCompanyImportSoap" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone spot my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to following link. This might help you.

http://ozkary.blogspot.in/2011/05/http-request-is-unauthorized-with.html

Answer (score 0):

I was using a couple of admin users to test the web service's Basic Authentication.  I do not know why, but they failed.  Finally I tried authenticating with a test user which had no privileges except for the ACL on the web service directory, and it worked.